# What is the Relationship b/w Opportunity products and opportunity Line Item

Tags: relationships, opportunity-lineitem

can any one help me out .What is the relation ship b/w Opportunity Products and Opportunity Line Item.Are their same or different in their behaviour.Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing. The UI shows "Opportunity Products", because it's the opportunity's products. IN the API, though, it uses the more "database-oriented" name of Opportunity Line Item (OpportunityLineItem), since each record is a line item on the opportunity.